# Figure caption additional text in same line

Tags: graphics, captions

I am using \includegraphicx to add a figure to my document. Now I would like to have a caption and also a longer explanation under the Figure.

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{figure.png}
\caption{This is my short caption for the list of figures}  
This is my longer text fur further information not to be displayed 
in the the table of contents.
\label{img:label}
\end{figure}
```

But unfortunately with this my longer text is placed in a new line after the caption but I want to have directly after the caption without a linebreak.

Is that possible somehow?

Comment: `\caption[short for list of figures]{longer for the document}`

Comment: I saw that solution, but in that case I would have to write the short caption twice since it is not printed below the figure as well. Thats why I thought it might be worth asking wether there is a better solution for that.

Comment: If you need it a lot you could define your own command, but such commands are rather document dependant and they are not so flexible -- what if the text below the caption should be completly different to the one in the lof? --, so it doesn't make much sense to define such a behaviour as a default.

Comment: You could put the repeated text into a macro.  Once you leave the figure environment the macro definition will be forgotten.